# What does Tuple.Item.Equals to?

Tags: c#, tuples

I am rewriting a tuple based C# code, I see below code snippet

```
Double[] rates = <values from somewhere>;
Tuple<Double[]> tuple1 = new Tuple<Double[]>(rates);
```

What happens with below ? The result of Equals is not assigned anywhere, is it just a dead code ?

```
tuple1.Item1.Equals(rates);
```

Comment: Since that's an array it's just going to do reference comparison and if the return is not captured and used then it is something that can be removed as it would not have any side effects.

Comment: Yes, it is just a dead code. This has nothing to do with `Tuple`. The method `Equals` doesn't change the objects, it just compares them and returns a Boolean result, so if the returned value is not captured then it's just a dead code.